# NextResponse.redirect() is not working in an API route

Tags: typescript, redirect, next.js

I am making a website using nextjs 13, prisma, and typescript. I am doing a post request from a form on `app/page.tsx` to `/app/api/posts`. In the `app/api/posts/route.ts` prisma creates a post and then returns it using `NextResponse.json()`. But I want to redirect the user to `/` route after creating the post, with or without showing the next response. So I thought of using `NextResponse.redirect()` but the page keeps loading forever but the post is created.

Here is the code for `app/api/posts/route.ts`:

```js
import { prisma } from "@/lib/database";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { authOptions } from "../auth/[...nextauth]/options";

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  const allPosts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    include: {
      comments: true,
      author: {
        select: {
          name: true,
          image: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });
  return NextResponse.json(allPosts);
}

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  const formData = await req.formData();
  const title = formData.get("title")?.toString() as string;
  const content = formData.get("content")?.toString() as string;

  const createTodo = await prisma.user.update({
    where: { email: session?.user?.email as string },
    data: {
      posts: {
        create: {
          title,
          content,
        },
      },
    },
  });
  return NextResponse.json(createTodo);
}
```

Here is the code for `app/page.tsx`:

```js
import Card from "@/components/Card";
import axios from "axios";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

const getPosts = async () => {
  const url =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? "http://localhost:3000/api/posts"
      : "https://dropconnect.vercel.app/api/posts";
  const res = await axios.get(url);
  const data = await res.data;

  return data;
};

export default async function Home() {
  const posts: mPost[] = await getPosts();
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.length === 0 ? (
        <div>
          <p>Currently there are 0 posts</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <div>
            <form
              className="flex flex-col gap-2"
              action="/api/posts"
              method="POST"
            >
              <input
                className="p-2 outline-none rounded-xl bg-secondary2"
                type="text"
                id="title"
                name="title"
                placeholder="What's on your mind?"
              />
              <textarea
                className="p-2 outline-none rounded-xl bg-secondary2"
                name="content"
                id="content"
                cols={30}
                rows={5}
                placeholder="Share your story...(Optional)"
              ></textarea>
              <button
                className="p-2 px-4 rounded-xl w-max ml-auto bg-blue-400 font-semibold text-xl"
                type="submit"
              >
                Post
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div>
            {posts.map((post: mPost) => (
              <div key={post.id}>
                <Card
                  id={post.id}
                  title={post.title}
                  content={post.content}
                  comments={post.comments}
                  noComments={post.noComments}
                  noLikes={post.noLikes}
                  name={post.author.name}
                  image={post.author.image}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

what am I doing wrong, and is there a fix?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: As far as I can see, you don't actually use NextResponse.redirect() anywhere in the code snippet you provided?

Comment: I did use it in the previous code, but it didn't work and had issues like the page would load for infinite time though the post was already created

Comment: I may be wrong as I've also had the same issue, but I believe NextResponse.redirect() is mainly meant to be used in Middleware.js. When you return it in a route handler, it just redirects your request to that route and returns the markup associated with that page. When you use it in middleware, it actually performs a redirect.

Comment: You are right. So can we use `useRouter()` hook to perform the redirect? because showing the API data to the user isn't a good practise and the UX falls apart

Comment: What I've done is use useRouter(), like you suggest, and push a route using router.push if the API responds with a success status.

Comment: Got it mate. Will do that. Thanks